Magento 2.4.5 Store Pick up not showing the stores
I configured the sources, stock inventory and also enable the Store Pick from the admin.
But at the checkout it shows the Store Pick text only not showing any store.

Check this guide for more information. Specifically the "Before setup" section.
Usually the issues solves by:

configured the store location.
Setup the location radius correctly
downloading the distance API files

I understand that you already have configured the sources geographic location correctly.

I enable the store pickup, it is showing Pick in Store on the storefront I want to show it on the shipping method place, customer just select it and places the order as same in the Magento default functionality  I have only one store I want to use as a just Shipping method I have also attached the ss of the storefront in the edited message
